# Log keyboard strokes below the OS level

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have a KVM switch that is connected to 4 networks. The KVM switches to the desired network after pressing the sequence control+control+[number 1-4], the number chooses the desired network.
I have 2 displays, one connected to the kvm and the second connects to each computer directly, therefore it does not switch network automatically with the KVM. I want to have a way to detect the commands to the KVM, in order to switch networks on the second monitor automatically. (I can achieve switching a network already, I just need a way to detect the command).

I tried to write python code that records keystrokes using the keyboard library, however the last keystroke (the number) seems not to register, which leads me to believe the keystroke does not register at the OS level.

Is there a way to log these keystrokes anyway, lower than the OS level?
A script will be preferable, however I am open to options.
Important to say that I cannot use a hardware device, and also I am using a windows PC.